# Fortran-Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference

Tags: segmentation-fault, fortran

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault
. The qden.dat file is a 30x30 matrix so I don't know what went wrong.

```
program poisson
 implicit none  
 integer :: ierror 
 integer :: ni,nj=30 ! input cell number in the x and y direct
 integer :: ii 
 real(16),allocatable :: q_den(:,:)

 integer :: lun_in


 allocate(q_den(0:ni+1,0:nj+1))

 ! initialize charge density
 q_den=0.0
open(newunit=lun_in,file='qden.dat',status='old',iostat=ierror)

! Read data into arrays
     do ii=1,30
        read(lun_in,*,iostat=ierror) q_den(1:30,ii)
     end do
 do ii=0,ni+1
    write(*,'(*(es16.4e2))') q_den(ii,:) 
 end do

 close(lun_in)

 deallocate(q_den)
 stop 0

end program poisson
```

Any help is appreciated. I'm pretty sure it's should just be a small typo.

Comment: Do you think `integer :: ni,nj=30` initializes `ni`?  (It doesn't.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is as at:

```
integer :: ni,nj=30
```

ni,nj=30 doesn't specify ni, it only assignes the value for nj.

Change it to

```
integer :: ni=30,nj=30
```

I would recommend

```
integer,parameter :: ni=30,nj=30
```

This ensures that the values ni,nj cannot be changed during the course of the program.